# Scaling an Image - Maintaining the position - Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Folks, I'm trying to scale an image both Shrink it and expand it, but maintain it's position in the image. Let me explain. Given an image below:
[image], I need to scale it but maintain the position.

I'm using the below code to do it, but it's not preserving the position. Any ideas?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageOps,ImageStat, ImageFilter
def scaling_thumbline(image1):
    scale = Image.new("1", image1.size, "white");
    image1.show()
    x = image1.size[0]
    y = image1.size[1]
    print (x,y)
    image2 = image1.resize((x/2,y/2),Image.ANTIALIAS);
    image2.show()
    print image2.size
    for x in range(0,image2.size[0]):
        for y in range(0,image2.size[1]):
            scale.putpixel((x,y),image2.getpixel((x,y)));

   scale.show()
   print scale.size



image1 = Image.open("Problems/Basic Problems C/Basic Problem C-02/A.png").convert("1");
scaling_thumbline(image1)
```

And I get, 
[image], I need to scale it but maintain the position. Notice how instead of in the middle, the image has moved to the top.

Any ideas? Help?

Comment: Why not just use image1.resize? Can you show an example image of what output you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [resize](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) function is what you are looking for. I tested the below code out using python 2.7.10 on Mac OSX Yosemite and got the correct results.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> a = Image.open('test.png')
>>> size = a.size
>>> newSize = tuple([dimension/10 for dimension in size])
>>> b = a.resize(newSize)
>>> a.show()
>>> b.show()
```